Как прописать в файле .bat много команд?
Как через планировщик задач сделать следующие действия?

открыть cmd
ввести команду. %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\anaconda3
перейти. cd C:\Users\name\Desktop\whisper-main
активировать среду. conda activate Whisper
запустить скрипт. C:\anaconda3\envs\Whisper\python.exe c:/fff/ct_call.py

заранее всем благодарен.

"Как прописать в файле .bat много команд?" - так и пишите, каждую команду с новой строки

@insolor я так их и прописал там, cmd открывается, выполняется 1я команда и больше ничего! сл строка не выполняется (cd C:\Users\name\Desktop\whisper-main)

Вам не нужно в bat файле "открывать cmd", он сам по себе уже в cmd запускается.

cmd открывается, выполняется 1я команда и больше ничего! Попробуйте почитать по батч-процессингу... ну хоть что-нибудь! Чтобы при выполнении дочернего батч-файла затем вернуться в точку вызова, необходимо использовать команду CALL.

Да, вот про call нужно не забывать.

conda activate Whisper  && C:\anaconda3\envs\Whisper\python.exe c:\DWH\imap_call.py

